# Is there a gcc command line option to silence warning: passing argument n discards qualifiers from type

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, constants, suppress-warnings

I'm trying to compile -Wall -Werror and its cramping my style.

I'm trying to make explicit that certain arguments are constants and then passing them to non const qualifying functions inside a large library.

P.S. I was mostly doing this to try to make it clear that certain variables are constants, is it good or bad c style to do this when dealing with a library functions that don't use const?

Comment: "Your style" being unsafe coding? ;-)

Comment: Maybe but I don't think so, I may go over some of the source code but I am fairly sure none of the functions modify the values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing those constants into routines as reference parameters or by pointer, then there may be a damn good reason for those warnings. How do you know that those routines won't modify your "constants"? What is that gonna screw up in the rest of your code, which you told that those variables won't ever change?

If you really know for sure that what you are doing is safe, and there is no good way to recode things to get rid of the warning, you can [turn some warnings off in gcc using pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas). Do this for as small an area of code as possible, and comment why you are doing it.

Do not abuse this privelege, or you are liable to arrested by the code police and sentenced to 9 months of community service coding in Ada. That'll cure you of ever complaining about C's warnings again.

Comment: The C language type system is quite laxist about `const`ness. And many people do not know there is even a `const` keyword in C. I have been `const_cast`ing a lot in C++ to be able to pass data to C libraries.

Comment: `const` does imply semantic read-only. The technical meaning might be different (on the other hand, it might not).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-Wno-ignored-qualifiers` switch.

Sometimes, when compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` (as I do too because it is *very good practice*), you face recurring warnings that you may want to disable project wide, or on a per source file basis. One that I disable often in my projects for instance is `-Wno-long-long`. This is not bad practice, because you know what you are doing, and you don't want to control third party code.

As I understand though, you are trying to disable the warning for specific parts of the code, since otherwise it would ruin your effort putting `const` everywhere. In this case, do:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wignored-qualifiers"

OffendingThirdPartyFunction(MyConstParam);

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

or also (untested, I don't know where to put the semicolons, and I don't have a working GCC here at work)

```
#define NO_WARNING(expr)                                        \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push")                              \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wignored-qualifiers\"")  \
    expr                                                        \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")

NO_WARNING(OffendingThirdPartyFunction(MyConstParam));
```

Alternatively, you can use a cast. This is by far the most portable solution.

```
OffendingThirdPartyFunction((param_t*)MyConstParam);
```

Comment: I think this answer is mistaken.  `-Wno-ignored-qualifiers` has only one purpose: to suppress warnings about qualifiers that have no effect, due to being placed where they don't really belong, such as function return values.  (Why that's a rule, I don't know, and wish it were different!)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a command-line option: the warning tells you that your code is not const-safe. It's right, your code *isn't* const-safe, although that's the fault of whoever wrote the library you're using.

If you disable the warnings then you won't get them any more even if you write code that's unsafe and it *is* your fault.

Instead, whenever one of the library functions takes a pointer-to-non-const, but guarantees not to modify the referand of the pointer, then cast the const-ness away from your pointer, and pass that. The cast serves as a record in the code that you (the programmer) are claiming that nothing invalid will happen, even though the type system can't prove that, and should probably be commented.

For example:

```
// in this library
void print_int(int *p) { printf("%d\n", *p); }
void set_int(int *p) { *p = 6; }

// your code
const int n = 5;
print_int((int*)(&n)); // warning suppressed for this call only,
                       // having carefully checked the print_int docs.

// further down your code
set_int(&n); // You *want* the compiler to stop this!
```

Or if you can be bothered (because you have a lot of such calls), write wrappers for the offending library functions:

```
void print_int_const(const int *p) { print_int((int*)(p)); }
// but no wrapper for set_int
```

Be aware that the cast also removes `volatile` (and in general accepts a lot of incorrect inputs). The overload prevents you accidentally using completely the wrong type, while the in-place cast doesn't.

Comment: And moreover, if it were C++, the code would not only have given warnings, it would have given an error.

Comment: @Alexandre: fair point. For C substitute a regular cast for the const_cast, and a function with a different name for the overload.